# Logic and sentences

Tags: logic

Never saw this type of question before and searched throughout the book and powerpoint, couldn't find it.

A little help would be greatly appreciated. :)

This is the question, Let P(x,y) be the statement "x loves y," where the domain for both x and y consists of everyone in the world. Use quantifiers to express each of these statements.

a) Everyone loves Janice
b) Everyone loves someone

I think I could figure out the rest if you I could find out what the question is asking and how do I attack this question. Thank you all. :)

Comment: $\forall$ - this is the universal quantifier which loosely translates into "for all" or "all" & $\exists$ - this is the existential quantifier which loosely translates into "there exists" or "exists".

Comment: Ok I understand those quantifiers, but these two variables has thrown me off. All of the other problems I have done well, but I'm stumped without more information... I think lol

Comment: Oh, thought you were unaware of what quantifiers are. See Newb's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S=\{x\mid x\mathrm{\ is\ a\ person}\}$

1. $\forall x\in S, P(x,\mathrm{Janice})$
2. $\forall x\in S, \exists y\in S\ \mathrm{s.t.}\ P(x,y)$

Comment: Is number 2 part b of the question?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if it would format as nicely if I did a, b

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is from Daniel Velleman's *How To Prove It*, which is a good book. If you're having difficulty with these exercises, you should read that book.

The key quantifiers you want to use here are $\forall$, which means *for all*, and $\exists$, which means *there exists*.

Note that "everyone loves Janice" is like saying "all people love Janice". We can split 'all people' up, and say "every person loves Janice." Then we're pretty close to saying "For every person $x$, $x$ loves Janice." And that's $\forall x, P(x,\text{Janice})$.

Similarly, "everyone loves someone" is like saying "for every person $x$, there is a someone whom they love." That's equivalent to "for every person $x$, there exists a person $y$ whom they love." So $\forall x, \exists y$ such that $P(x,y)$.

Comment: In particular it is a good book, but it's much more than a good book. It should be mandatory for every mathematics student.

Comment: Today is the first day I attempted it, I will look into that book. He assigned it yesterday and it is due tomorrow so I am stumped lol... Will definitely look into that book though, Thanks!!!!

Comment: Thanks for all of the help guys! Okay, another question, this is unfamiliar matter to me. What does P(x, Janice) mean? Sorry for the dumb question but I'm trying to understand everything so I can understand what to actually do. :)

Comment: @RichSanchez You defined P(x,y) as the statement "x loves y". So P(x,Janice) means "x loves Janice".

Comment: Oh now I get it.... (I think... hopefully LOL)